# changing cell background color in qt

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

i'm new to pyqt , and i'm still facing some newbie problems :D
i have a QTableWidget that is item delegated on a QChoice control ( hope i said it right ) 
i need to have the cell  background color changes whenever a user change the choice control selection 

briefly: how to change a cell background color in a table widget ??

i use pyqt4 and python 2.6

thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.item(row, column)
```

and

```
QTableWidgetItem setData(role, data)
```

with

```
Qt.BackgroundRole
```

as follows:

```
table.item(0, 0).setData(Qt.BackgroundRole, color).
```

And read about the Roles mechanism used in Qt Model/View.

Answer (score 9):

I used something like this:

```
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
item.setBackground(brush)
```

Where item is QTableWidgetItem object

Answer (score 2):

if you use QTableView use this:

```
model.setData(model.index(0, 0), QVariant(QBrush(Qt::red)), Qt::BackgroundRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful lines of code.  Sorry for redundancy, I'm trying to gain some reputation.

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(numRows, numColumns);
QStringList headers;
headers.append("Date");
model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(text);
item->setData(Qt::AlignCenter, Qt::TextAlignmentRole);
item->setData(QVariant(QBrush(Qt::green)), Qt::BackgroundRole);
model->setItem(row, column, item);
```

or simply:

```
item->setBackground(Qt::green);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey, you set the delegate method for the table widget. in the paint event of the delegate you handle the color changing technique..
have a look at this [example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtextended4.4/messageviewer.html),here they have done custom selection color. same way you handle the item cell painting

Answer (score 0):

For supplement in C++ way, if you want to paint custom color unlike Qt::red and so on, you can do something like :
`ui->tableWidget->item(i, j)->setBackground(QColor(152,234,112));`