# Starting with Qt (cell colour in a table)

Tags: qt

In the QtDesigner I have created Field.ui. On the form I have placed a tableWidget Glass.
Well, I'm making Tetris and it's my first experience with Qt. So, the tableWidget has 10 columns and 22 lines.

Could you help me get to know how to change the colour of a certain cell. Say, left hand bottommost. I'm having troubles with two matters: 1) what to write 2) where to write it.

Your assistance would be highly appreciated.

My code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create and show your widgets here
    Field form;
    form.show();



    return app.exec();
}
```

**Field.cpp**

```
Field::Field() {
    widget.setupUi(this);
}

Field::~Field() {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a cell in a table widget has been covered here: [changing cell background color in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806189/changing-cell-background-color-in-qt) 
However, if you're trying to make Tetris, there are better ways than using a QTableWidget. Take a look at using QML or the QGraphics systems.